# Inner join query where excluding multiple entries if NULL exists

Tags: sql, postgresql, inner-join

I have an application in which users answer 10 questions, and then get a final score based on the answers. The users are in one table, and answers in another - these are linked by the User's PK (userid). When a user starts a test 10 (empty) rows are created for that user, and the `answer` value gets set to null.

I need a way to create a query to calculate the average score for all users where the full 10 questions have been answered (i.e. NOT NULL) and group these by average .

### Users table:

```
| userid |  location  |     name    |
|--------|------------|-------------|
| 1      | New York   |     John    |
| 2      | Chicago    |     Mike    |
| 3      | New York   |     Daisy   |
| 4      | Los Angeles|     Jane    |
| 5      | Chicago    |     Bob     |
```

### Answers table:

```
| aId | userid | answer |question|
|-----|--------|--------|--------|
| 001 | 1      |   8    |   1    |
| 002 | 1      |   7    |   2    |
| 003 | 1      |   5    |   3    |
| 004 | 1      |   3    |   4    |
| 005 | 1      |  10    |   5    |
| 006 | 1      |   3    |   6    |
| 007 | 1      |   6    |   7    |
| 008 | 1      |   4    |   8    |
| 009 | 1      |   2    |   9    |
| 010 | 1      |   8    |  10    |
| 011 | 2      |   8    |   1    |
| 012 | 2      |   7    |   2    |
| 013 | 2      |   5    |   3    |
| 014 | 2      |   3    |   4    |
| 015 | 2      |  NULL  |   5    |
| 016 | 2      |  NULL  |   6    |
| 017 | 2      |  NULL  |   7    |
| 018 | 2      |  NULL  |   8    |
| 019 | 2      |  NULL  |   9    |
| 020 | 2      |  NULL  |  10    |
....
```

In the example above there is one user with 10 answered questions, and one user with only 4 answered questions. The goal is to exclude `User #2` from the query, while only selecting `User #1` (and other users with a full result)

This is my statement so far, but it does not exclude the answers for the users that have null values. What I would need is some sort of if-statement to check something like (`IF a.answer IS NULL` "don't use this users' answers")

```
SELECT AVG(a.answer), u.clocation FROM answers a 
INNER JOIN users u 
ON u.userid = a.userid
GROUP BY u.clocation;
```

#### I would like to:

1. Calculate the average score for each user with 10 questions answered (and filter out all 10 answers for users with one or more answers as NULL).
2. Group these by city
3. Calculate a new average by city

Is this even possible to do in one query?

Comment: Show us the expected result as well! (Having the above table data.)

Comment: "with 10 questions answered", do you mean at least 10, or exactly 10?

Comment: I mean exactly 10 as there is only 10 answers in the quiz. So if the user has answered all of them the query should show it – otherwise not

Answer (score 0):

I think you want multiple levels of aggregation, first by user, then by location.  I think:

```
SELECT u.clocation, AVG(avg_answer)
FROM (SELECT a.userid, AVG(a.answer) as avg_answer
      FROM answers a
      WHERE a.answer IS NOT NULL
      GROUP BY a.userid
      HAVING COUNT(*) = 10
     ) a JOIN
     users u
     ON u.userid = a.userid
GROUP BY u.clocation;
```

If all users have ten rows -- even for unanswered questions, then you could also do:

```
SELECT u.clocation, AVG(a.answer)
FROM answers a JOIN
     users u
     ON u.userid = a.userid
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM answers a2
                  WHERE a2.userid = a.userid AND
                        a2.answer IS NOT NULL
                 )
GROUP BY u.clocation;
```

However, I think I prefer the first version, because it does not require that all users have all ten rows in the table.